# How to create batch file using command line?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Please look the below mentioned command line which need to be converted as batch file.

```
C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\
START /wait TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"C:\AMG\trunk\AMG_AccountManager\AMC\Core" /closeonend:1
```

I have no idea of creating batch file  also i know this is very easy but hard for me.

i have tried like below

```
cmd -k C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin> START TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"C:\SVN_TRUNK" /closeonend:1
```

Comment: In a batch file you can really just write like you are in the cmd i would help you more but i dont understand what you wanna do in the second line.

Comment: @WasteD second command from commanad one for creating batch file

Comment: No i mean is the command `/command:update` an argument of Tortoise?

Comment: That is the command which use to run task in bin folder also this is working when i used go with command line

Comment: i am having the issue while converting this to batch file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
cd C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\
TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"C:\AMG\trunk\AMG_AccountManager\AMC\Core" /closeonend:1
```

Then just Name the file like you want .bat (myScript.bat) and doubleclick it.